# onchange works for ASP.net DropDownList but not for RadCombobox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, onchange, radcombobox

In ASP.net Control is used DropDownList Onchange as followes:
In ASCX:

```
onchange="dorefreshf();dorefreshs();"
```

When I replaced the DropDownList with a RadComboBox the JS doesn't work?

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using update panel of any kind e.g. RadAjaxPanel

Comment: Yes, ASP.net Update Panel, is it related?

Comment: Check your browser console if there is any error. I encountered the problem sometimes ago. It's conflict between the Panel script and RadComboBox script. I think getting an updated verison of Telerik did it

Comment: i am using the latest version! however, i will try again, BTW, @endyourif, suggestion below worked for OnClick! why not for OnChange!

Comment: does OnClick trigger a postback? Did you even set AutoPostBack="True"?

Comment: I don't think OnClick do a postback, that would explains why it works. The Onchange would cause postback and thus the conflict, but confirm this from your browser console for javascript error as I said earlier. However, that might not be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing (no pun intended) onchange to onclick.

Comment: @endyyourif, It's working!! but i need the onchange or onselectedindexchanged , i am wondering why the Onclick is working and Onchange is not!!